# Displaying the changed paragraph and reseting the paragraph in original form

Tags: jquery

I am working to display the changed paragraph that occur in the span. Initially this is the code for HTML.

```
<div>
         <p><span id="spnOne">This text will change.</span></p>
</div>
```

I change the original text to

Text Before ++ Text at the front --New Text for the Span == Text at the back@@Text After by using append, prepend, before and after.

I have this button.

```
<div>
   <button id="btnResetChanges">Reset Paragraph Text</button>
</div>
```

When I click this button I want to change all of the changes that occurs so that it returns to the original state .

I tried to do

```
$("#btnResetChanges").click(function () {
  ($("#spnOne").remove());

});
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first]
(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I try to do  
 $("#btnResetChanges").click(function () {
      ($("#spnOne").remove());
   
    });
But it is not working.

Comment: Store content of element in variable before change and after change on button click get variable content