# Reseting the changes of paragrapgh

Tags: jquery

I am working to display the changed paragraph that occurs in the span. Initially, this is the code for HTML.

```
<div>
   <p><span id="spnOne">This text will change.</span></p>
</div>
```

I change the original text to :

Text Before ++ Text at the front --New Text for the Span == Text at the back@@Text After by using append, prepend, before and after.

I have this button.

```
<div>
   <button id="btnResetChanges">Reset Paragraph Text</button>
</div>
```

When I click this button I want to change all of the changes that occurs so that it returns to the original state .

I tried to do

```
$("#btnResetChanges").click(function () {
  ($("#spnOne").reset());

});
```

Comment: `reset()` is not a jQuery method.  It's a native method, which is intended to reset form fields.  Paragraphs are not form fields.  If you want to "reset" a paragraph, you are going to have to keep track of the original value yourself, and do the reset yourself.

Comment: @Taplar can you help me by giving an example. That would really be awesome

Comment: @Taplar is correct.   You should use a method to store the original paragraph using something like `local storage` -- Here is a great read on using `local storage` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791207/setting-and-getting-localstorage-with-jquery

Comment: You should store the value in a local param and then reset it it in javascript or jquery, I dont think so there is any API which reset it.

Comment: Easiest approach would be to store the original value on the paragraph as a data field.  No reason to put it in localStorage and make it more global than it has to be.

Comment: @Taplar .. Good call -- unless this is an "undo" function which is what I was assuming .. so there could be multiple versions of the paragraph needing reset ..  At this point local storage would be more efficient.

Comment: Also @rebbecca --  Asking multiple questions with the same content is frowned upon on Stack Overflow:  --> 
 **original question** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552955/displaying-the-changed-paragraph-and-reseting-the-paragraph-in-original-form

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies and local storage in this case, but I would suggest to you to store the original paragraph using `data-* attributes` then call it when you want to reset, something like :

```js
$('#spnOne').append('++++').prepend('----');

$('#btnResetChanges').click(function() {
  $('#spnOne').text($('#spnOne').data('original'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p><span id="spnOne" data-original="This text will change.">This text will change.</span></p>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="btnResetChanges">Reset Paragraph Text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//if you don't want to preload the data fields in the html
//you can set them with the javscript
var $changable = $('.changable').each(function(){
  $(this).data('originalHtml', this.innerHTML);
});

//when the button is clicked, change all the fields back to what is
//in their original data field
$('#btnResetChanges').on('click', function(){
  $changable.html(function(index, element){
    return $(this).data('originalHtml');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p><span class="changable" contenteditable="true">This text will change.</span></p>
  <p><span class="changable" contenteditable="true">This text will change.</span></p>
  <p><span class="changable" contenteditable="true">This text will change.</span></p>
</div>


<div>
  <button id="btnResetChanges">Reset Paragraph Text</button>
</div>
```